# What is difference between spin_lock and spin_lock_bh

Tags: linux-kernel, spinlock

I want to understand difference between spin_lock and spin_lock_bh. 

As per
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/kernel-hacking/locking.html#cheat-sheet-for-locking 

if critical section is between softirq and userspace process 

    we should use spin_lock_bh. 

if between two softirq 

    we should use spin_lock.

Comment: `spin_lock_bh` prevents a softirq running on the same CPU as the caller while the lock is held. Since the userspace process can be preempted by a softirq, this prevents a deadlock from occurring if a softirq waits for a spin-lock that is already locked by the same CPU.

Comment: Can you please explain using code reference as how softirq are disabled on that core using spin_lock_bh.

Comment: It increases the "softirq" count which is part of the "preempt" count for the current CPU so that the task cannot be preempted by other tasks and so that `in_interrupt()` (defined in "include/linux/preempt.h") is true. After any hardware interrupt servicing by the CPU, the usual pending softirq processing invoked by `irq_exit()` (in "kernel/softirq.c") is suppressed due to `in_interrupt()` being true.

Comment: Ok. Thanks got it